# Python Doesn't Have Permission To Access On This Server / Return City/State from ZIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

What I'm trying to do is retrieve the city and state from a zip code. Here's what I have so far:

```
def find_city(zip_code):
    zip_code = str(zip_code)
    url = 'http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/' + zip_code
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    index = plain_text.find(">")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")
    stuff = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12'})
```

I also tried using id="zip-links", but that didn't work. But here's the thing: when I run `print(plain_text)` I get the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /80123
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

So I guess my question is this: is there a better way to get a city and state from a zip code? Or is there a reason that unitedstateszipcodes.gov isn't cooperating. After all, it is easy enough to see the source and tags and text. Thank you

Comment: Not really a python question, but you can try the post office:

    https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&postalCode=10023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are taking a longer route to solve an easy problem!

Try [pyzipcode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzipcode/)

```
>>> from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
>>> zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
>>> zipcode = zcdb[54115]
>>> zipcode.zip
u'54115'
>>> zipcode.city
u'De Pere'
>>> zipcode.state
u'WI'
>>> zipcode.longitude
-88.078959999999995
>>> zipcode.latitude
44.42042
>>> zipcode.timezone
-6
```

Comment: I couldn't actually get pyzipcode to work (sometimes my modules won't download), but I ended up using the .csv file that was on the link you sent. Is pyzipcode only for Linux, because I only saw a .tar.gz link?

Comment: Use `pip` to download modules.

Comment: Pip failed, too :( Again, I saw it downloading x.tar.gz, but I'm not sure why

Answer (score 16):

You need to add a user-agent:

```
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"}
def find_city(zip_code):
    zip_code = str(zip_code)
    url = 'http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/' + zip_code
    source_code = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Once you do, the response is 200 and you get the source:

```
In [8]:  url = 'http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/54115'

In [9]: headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"}

In [10]:  url = 'http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/54115'
In [11]: source_code = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
In [12]: source_code.status_code
Out[12]: 200
```

If you want the details it is easily parsed:

```
In [59]:  soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")

In [60]: soup.find('div', id='zip-links').h3.text
Out[60]: 'ZIP Code: 54115'

In [61]: soup.find('div', id='zip-links').h3.next_sibling.strip()
Out[61]: 'De Pere, WI 54115'

In [62]:  url = 'http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/90210'

In [63]: source_code = requests.get(url,headers=headers).text

In [64]:  soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")

In [65]: soup.find('div', id='zip-links').h3.text
Out[66]: 'ZIP Code: 90210'

In [70]: soup.find('div', id='zip-links').h3.next_sibling.strip()
Out[70]: 'Beverly Hills, CA 90210'
```

You could also store each result in a database and first try to do a lookup in the database.