# 403 forbidden error. can't access to this site

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to scrape https://health.usnews.com/doctors/specialists-index while sending a request to this site through scrapy spider it shows status code as 403. In my request, I added `user_agent` but also it's not working.

I referred these two answer [Python Doesn't Have Permission To Access On This Server / Return City/State from ZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467410/python-doesnt-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-return-city-state-from) and [403:You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485301/403you-dont-have-permission-to-access-index-php-on-this-server/43485545) but it's not working for me.

my `user_agent` is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36`. Some one help me to scrape the above mentioned site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add 'authority' in the headers as well. The below works for me in scrapy shell:

```
from scrapy import Request
headers = {
     'authority': 'health.usnews.com',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
}
url = "https://health.usnews.com/doctors/specialists-index"
req = Request(url, headers=headers)
fetch(req)
```